# How To Make ListView.Builder's items appear within the screen width?

Tags: list, flutter, listview

Is it possible to use one ListView.Builder to populate all its items to different rows within the screen's width?

Currently, my makeshift method is having 2 ListView.Builders. This cuts the list I have into half. I would like the ListView.Builder to showcase everything in the list within the screen's width limits. If there's not enough space, then populate the interests to another row.

The name of the list is interests, and it is a list of strings.

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 6, 0, 0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.039,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        itemCount: 5,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  border:
                                      Border.all(color: Colors.yellow[100])),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.030,
                                  vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.0045),
                              child: Text(
                                interests[index],
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              ));
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 3, 0, 0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.039,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        itemCount: 4,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  border:
                                      Border.all(color: Colors.yellow[100])),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.030,
                                  vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.0045),
                              child: Text(
                                interests[5 + index],
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              ));
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
```

[My current example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np92E.png): 2 Listviews possibly flowing out of the screen.

The results I want:
[Container bubbles filling up within screen's width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5aLD.png) and if the last bubble will overflow the screen, it automatically forms a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter's `Wrap` widget provides this exact functionality.

By default `Wrap` lays it's children `horizontally` and automatically wraps it's children when they are overflowing out of the given contraints.

Use it like this,

```
// Suppose you have data like this.
List<String> interests = ['Bollywood','Biryani','Running','Punjabi','Dancing'];

// Use them inside build function like this
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.039,
  child: Wrap(
    children: interests.map((interest) => Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 9),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow[100])),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.030,
        vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0045
      ),
      child: Text(
        interest,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
      ),
    )).toList()
  ),
),
```

Result is this

[image]

Comment: @VegetaSaiyan. Does this answer solve your use case ?

Comment: thans Nisanth. That makes sense. but wrap has children, whereas my listview builder is a sort of a container (a single child that repeats itself according to the number of items in my list), how do I go about progressing such that wrap can take only a child (Listview builder)?

Comment: @VegetaSaiyan I have updated my code. You can use the `map` on your `interests` array and then return your single child `Container` inside `map`.

Comment: thanks Nisanth! your code's good! For the height of the container, how do I make it flexible? Bcos there might be 3 rows instead of 2. Do I wrap the container w a flexible or expanded?

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Ideally you shouldn't have to give any constraint to the `Container`, the `Wrap` widget automatically goes to the next line and the `Container` will automatically take the height of the wrap widget.

Comment: got it, I have removed the height constraints for the container. It works.